# how to push existing div from one column to another column if one div is removed from that column in angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular, angular6

[image]

In this above image, there are 3 column having 3 input fields each, in the second column one div is remove which is showing as blank space, I want that div from next column should be shifted to 2nd column and If there will be another row then div from the column of that row also be shifted, So on..

[image]

Above image is of component.html

If there is any programmatic way to do this in component.ts file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add multiple `<div class="row">` make it simple. Thanks

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4" *ngIf="isCompanyname">
    <div class="form-group"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" *ngIf="isRatingstatus">
    <div class="form-group"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" *ngIf="isIndustry">
    <div class="form-group"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" *ngIf="isClientclassificationbd">
    <div class="form-group"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" *ngIf="isSector">
    <div class="form-group"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" *ngIf="isSubindustry">
    <div class="form-group"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" *ngIf="isCompanycode">
    <div class="form-group"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" *ngIf="isIndustrygroup">
    <div class="form-group"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" *ngIf="isSilmapping">
    <div class="form-group"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Your HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" *ngIf="isCompanyname">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" *ngIf="isCompanyname">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" *ngIf="isCompanyname">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7u96mhp3/1/

Comment: if you will remove <div class="col-sm-4" *ngIf="isCompanyname"> then there will be one blank space in that row ...